# Problem with jqDock - is not a function

Tags: jquery

I done website, on a hard disc all it's ok, but if I sent my website to server jqDock dosen't load... In my validators I get communit : ('#menu').jqDock is not a function...

Where can be problem? I load jqDock library after jQuery ...

code..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // set up the options to be used for jqDock...
    var dockOptions =
        { align: 'left' // vertical menu, with expansion LEFT/RIGHT from the center
        , inactivity: 4000 // set inactivity timeout to 4 seconds
        , size: 222
        , distance: 40
        };
    // ...and apply...
    $('#menu').jqDock(dockOptions);
    $('#submenu').hide();


});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referencing the path of the jqDock.js wrong. So check your HTML and make sure that you linking to the jqDock file properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your/path/to/jqDock.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, my path was OK, but I checked files on server, there capital letters was changed on small letter, and was - jquery.jqdock.min.js (in HTML I had jquery.jqDock.min.js) so I changed capital letter 'D' and now it's ok...

Thanks for suggest...